# C++: where to place constructor in inheritance chain?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have following dilemma:

I have a full abstract class. Each inheriting class will need 3 same parameters. Each of them will additionally need other specific parameters.

I could:

1) implement a common constructor for initializing 3 common parameters in my base class, but then I have to make non-abstract getters for corresponding fields (they are private).

OR

2) leave my base class abstract and implement constructors in inherited classes, but then I have to make it in each class fields for common parameters.

Which is a better approach? I don't want to use protected members.

Comment: I don't see what constructor parameters have to do with getters for class members. Either you don't need the getters, or you do. I don't see what this has to do with the various constructors in the class. What you might be looking for is delegated constructors.

Comment: however if I place fields as private in my base class, then each derived class needs access to private memebers of base class, where are common parameters stored. Therefor needs the descendant the getters.

Comment: This is what protected inheritance is for.

Answer (score 3):

An abstract class is one who has at least one pure virtual (or, as you call it, abstract) function. Having non-abstract, non-virtual functions does not change the fact that your class is abstract as long as it has at least one pure virtual function. Go for having the common functionality in your base class, even if it is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

If your class looks like this, a pure abstract class:

```
class IFoo {
   public:
    virtual void doThings() = 0;
}

class Foo {
   public:
      Foo(std::string str);
     void doThings() override;
}
```

The value your inheritance has is to provide you with the oppurtunity to subsitute Foo with another at runtime, but hiding concrete implementations behind interfaces. You can't use that advantage with Constructors, there's no such thing as a virtual constructor (that's why things like the [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) exist). All your implementations of `Foo` take a `std::string` and all your implementations of `doThings` use that string? Great, but that's a coincidence not a contract and doesn't belong in `IFoo`.

Lets talk about if you've created concrete implementations in `IFoo`, so that it's a abstract class and not a pure abstract class (`IFoo` would be a bad name now btw). **(*1)** Lets assume using inheritance to share behaviour was the correct choice for you class, which is sometimes true. If the class has fields that need to be initialised create a `protected` constructor (to be called from every child implementation) and remove/ommit the default one.

```
class BaseFoo {
       private:
         std::string _fooo;
       protected:
         BaseFoo(std::string fooo) : _fooo(fooo) {}
       public:
         virtual void doThings() = 0;
         std::string whatsTheBaseString() { return _fooo;}
   }
```

Above is the way you correctly pass fields needed by a base class from the child constructor. This is a compile time guarantee that a child class will 'remember' to initialize `_fooo` correctly and avoids exposing the actual member `fooo` to child classes. Trying to initialize `_fooo` in all the child constructors directly would be incorrect here.

***1)** Quickly, why? [Composition may be a better tool here?](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose).

Comment: Depends on type of inheritance, private inheritance can implement uses- relationships, and a private base class may well have data members.

Comment: I think this answer is exact what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: @ErikAlapää I don't like private inheritance, i think I've explained why in my answer now. I think it was a good design decision when languages like `C#` removed it.

Comment: A good design guideline is to prefer composition to inheritance, but there are good, sound use cases for private inheritance. Look at the writings of Stroustrup and Sutter and other C++ gurus for examples and guidelines. Interfaces (pure abstract) are usually the way to go, but I think it is a powerful feature to have private inheritance, for the use cases where it is natural.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid code duplication without polluting your abstract interface with data members, is by introducing an additional level of inheritance:

```
// Only pure virtual functions here
class Interface {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

// Things shared between implementations
class AbstractBase : public Interface {

};

class ImplementationA : public AbstractBase {
};

class ImplementationB : public AbstractBase {
};
```